# How to calculate the spectral(eigen) decomposition of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I am aiming to find the spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix. From what I understand of spectral decomposition; it breaks down like this:

For a symmetric matrix $B$, the spectral decomposition is $VDV^T$ where V is orthogonal and D is a diagonal matrix.

Now the way I am tackling this is to set $V$ to be an $nxn$ matrix consisting of the eigenvectors in columns corresponding to the positions of the eigenvalues i will set along the diagonal of $D$.

The problem I am running into is that V is not orthogonal, ie $V*V^T$ does not equal the identity matrix( I am doing all of this in $R$). Any help would be appreciated, an example on a simple 2x2 or 3x3 matrix would help me greatly.

Comment: Are your eigenvectors normed, ie have length of one?

Comment: I dont think I have normed them @Laray , Do they need to be normed for the decomposition to hold? for R, I am using eigen to find the matrix of vectors but the output just looks wrong. Ive done the same computation on symbolab and I have been getting different results, does the eigen function normalize the vectors?

Comment: Can you print $V\cdot V^T$ and look at it? If it is diagonal, you have to norm them. If not, there is something else wrong. There must be a decomposition $B=VDV^T$

Comment: I can and it does not, I think the problem is that the eigen function in R does not give the correct eigenvectors, for example a 3x3 matrix of all 1's on symbolab gives $(-1,1,0)$ as the first eigenvector while on R its $(0.8, -0.4,0.4)$ I will try and manually calculate the eigenvectors, thank you  for your help though.

Comment: @123123 Try with an arbitrary $V$ which is orthogonal (e.g. $I$); any orthogonal matrix should work.